# Use println! macro for "0xDEADBEEF"

Tags: rust

I just want to play with `DEADBEEF` like this:

```
println!("0x{:X}", "0xDEADBEEF");
```

And I got this:

> the trait bound `str: std::fmt::UpperHex` is not satisfied
>
> the trait `std::fmt::UpperHex` is not implemented for `str`

What I do wrong, why I am not able to print the value?

Comment: To print with a `0x` prefix, you can (and should) use the `{:#X}` formatter instead - so you could do `println!("{:#X}", 0xDEADBEEFu32);`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just do not wrap the value into a `str`, and use a proper type marker, `u32` would do:

```rust
fn main() {
    println!("0x{:X}", 0xDEADBEEFu32);
}
```